# Write an element of a permutation group as a product of generators in SageMath

Tags: group-theory, permutations, sagemath

For instance, let's say I have this group in Sage (taken from an example in the docs):

```
G = PermutationGroup(['(1,2)(3,4)', '(3,4,5,6)'], canonicalize=False)
```

The permutation `(1,2)(3,5,6)` is in this group, and can be shown to be the product of the two generators. Is there any way to make Sage decompose an arbitrary element of a permutation group into a product of the group's generators automatically (and efficiently)? Since Sage *can* efficiently tell me if an arbitrary permutation is in a given permutation group, it seems like this *should* be possible, but I haven't found any way to do it.

Comment: Hi. This question is about the usage of SageMath, NOT the math behind it or something similar. This might be out of the scope of present SE site.

Comment: @xbh Hmm, I thought this would be an appropriate place to ask this question because I've seen a lot of other Sage-related questions on this site. Aren't questions like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4523838/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-do-finite-field-arithmetic-in-sage) also about usage of Sage, or are these different in some way? Also, is there anywhere else you would recommend that I ask? Thanks!

Comment: Then if that' s the case, I have nothing more to say. Welcome here by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is called `word_problem`. Here's an example:

```
G = PermutationGroup(['(1,2)(3,4)', '(3,4,5,6)'], canonicalize=False)
p = G('(1,2)(3,5,6)')
ans = p.word_problem(G.gens())
```

This produces the following solution:

```
x1^-1*x2
[['(1,2)(3,4)', -1], ['(3,4,5,6)', 1]]
```

[Source](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/10267/writing-a-given-permutaion-as-a-product-of-generators/), [Docs](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/groups/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup_element.html#sage.groups.perm_gps.permgroup_element.PermutationGroupElement.word_problem)